# Is it possible to have the array declaration first and initialize it in a loop?

Tags: java

I recently worked on a program in which, I wanted the program to read a non negative value and then initialize the array in every iteration. I declared the array.This is the code..

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
class Array
{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = 0;
        int [] array;
        boolean end = false ;
        while (end != true)
        {
            array = new int[i];
            int x = in.nextInt();
            if(x > 10)
            {
                array[i] = x ;
            }
            if(x < 0)
            {
                end = true;
                for (int j : array)
                {
                    System.out.print(x + " ");
                }
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute this code I get an Exception saying

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>           at Array.main(Array.java:15)

when I give a value greater to 10. And it prints the negative number from the array. Is this method of declaring the array and dynamically changing the size correct?

Comment: You cannot change the size of the array after initializing it

Comment: `i` is initially zero, so you create a zero length array. Then you try to access the zero-th element of it, which is out of bounds

Comment: Also, your question is not very clear. If it is a negative number, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Explaining what your endgoal is - not just how you're trying to achieve it - might help us help you.

Comment: In any case you might want to look up ['ArrayList'](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: Every time the line `array = new int[i];` is run, _everything_ stored in `array` up to that point is thrown away.  You _cannot_ dynamically change the size of Java arrays.  You can use an API like `ArrayList` that takes care of the details of a dynamically sized array, though.

Answer (score 0):

While doing `int[] array;` an array of size 0 is initlaized.  Afterwards you try to access an element of an array with size 0, so you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Once the array is initialized, you cannot change its size.
For doing that, you will have to use a List, for example an `ArrayList`.

Those size can be extended or changed after their initialization.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my question and dropping some suggestions. I've understood why it wasn't working and looking into ArrayLists.

Comment: Great to hear it helped and you are looking towards more advanced data structures like lists:)